# How do you duplicate a record which consist of an attachment?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've got myself in trouble working with attachments. I wanted to be able to duplicate a record for easy entry but I am stuck. The RegNo on the database is a unique field that does not allow duplicates. The expectation is that I copy all the data to a form and `SetFocus` on `txtRegNo` so that a user can input this information before the record is saved. Is this even possible in Access or am I just wasting my time? Please see my code below. I have also attached images. Your help and guidance is highly appreciated:

```
Private Sub btnDuplicateRecord_Click()

Me![Make].DefaultValue = "'" & Me![Make] & "'"
Me![Model].DefaultValue = "'" & Me![Model] & "'"
Me![EngineSize].DefaultValue = "'" & Me![EngineSize] & "'"
Me![Qty].DefaultValue = "'" & Me![Qty] & "'"
Me![MOTDue].DefaultValue = "'" & Me![MOTDue] & "'"
Me![MarketValue].DefaultValue = "'" & Me![MarketValue] & "'"
Me![VehicleImage].DefaultValue = "'" & Me![VehicleImage] & "'"

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
txtRegNo.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Another try:

```
 Dim db As DAO.Database
 Dim rsParent As DAO.Recordset2
 Dim rsChild As DAO.Recordset2
 Dim strSQL As String

 Set db = CurrentDb
 strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblCars"
 Set rsParent = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
 Set rsChild = rsParent.Fields("VehicleImage").Value
 rsParent.Edit
 DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToNew
 rsChild.AddNew
 rsChild.Fields("FileData") = rsChild.Fields("FileData")
 rsChild.Fields("FileName") = rsChild.Fields("FileName")
'rsChild.Update

'rsParent.Update

 RegNo.SetFocus
```

[image: Before btnDuplicateRecord is clicked]

[image: Currently, this is what I am getting]

[image: This is what I expect]

Comment: Here is how to [copy the attachment(s) of a record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57153992/how-do-you-copy-the-entire-record-from-one-table-to-another-including-attachment/57163986#57163986).

Comment: Embedding files in db uses up Access 2GB size limit. Leave files external and save path in text field. Can still display images with path field in ControlSource property of Image control and simplify code.

Comment: Teach your users to use Ctrl+' (apostrophe). This copies to the current field whatever was on that same field in the previous record.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @Gustav the problem is copying the current record including the attachment field require the recordset to be updated and this is nearly impossible with a required field. I have also tried using DAO. Please see updated code.

Comment: Will have to add attachment after record is committed. Code will need source and destination Recordsets with filter criteria. Otherwise, abandon embedded files.

Comment: Why would you want to use up Access file size limit with multiple copies of same file embedded in records? If you must embed images then have an Images table and save RecID of image into data record. Retrieve image by joining tables.

Comment: _copying the current record including the attachment field require the recordset to be updated and this is nearly impossible with a required field_ .. Of course. That's the point why a field is required. So, either make the field not required or fill in a dummy value.